# Wrap text in a box with CSS, HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm displaying the output of a real-time running log file which can be very long (and wide) and looking for a way to bound (box) it inside a  border.
The page itself is HTML/PHP and I've been trying with CSS with various parameters but can't get it right.
This is what I've tried:

```
.log_output {
border:1px solid #999999;
color:#6f6f6f;
font-size:10px;
display:block;
float:left;
width:100%;
height:100px;
display: block; 
position: relative;
}
```

But the log text ignores the box and is displayed all over the page.

An ideal solution would show only the last few lines (or 100px for example) of the running log.
I'm open to using JS or whatever if needed.

Comment: Try adding `overflow: scroll`

Comment: did anything worked for u??

Comment: OK the text is boxed now using `inline-block; overflow:scroll; But the box is showing the text from the beginning so the box seems static as the log keeps growing. Is there a way to center on the **end** of the log? To show only the last few lines as it grows?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following CSS::

```
.log_output{
  border:1px solid #999999;
  color:#6f6f6f;
  font-size:10px;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
 }
```

You have to set 'display:inline-block' and 'height:auto' to wrap the content within the border.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways are there.

First is you can set auto height so that height will be adjust according to the text like this

```
.log_output {
border:1px solid #999999;
color:#6f6f6f;
font-size:10px;
display:block;
float:left;
width:100%;
display: block; 
position: relative;
}
```

No need to mention height in this it will be auto by default.

And if you need to set height fixed then use this css

```
.log_output {
border:1px solid #999999;
color:#6f6f6f;
font-size:10px;
display:block;
float:left;
width:100%;
height:100px;
display: block; 
position: relative;
overflow:auto;
}
```

This will show scrollbar in the box (if needed) and if text is short no scrollbar will come

> its up to you which way you want to go with

Comment: a combination of your answer and @WisdmLabs gets me nearly there: `border:1px solid #999999;
    color:#6f6f6f;
    font-size:10px;
    width:100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow:auto;`  But is there a way to keep the display showing only the most bottom lines of the output?

Comment: what left?? do u need anything else??

Comment: @o_ren could use JavaScript for that part. Whenever text is added, trigger scroll to bottom. I'd use jquery.

Comment: @Buttle Butkus Perhaps you have an example on how to implement this?

Comment: @o_ren it's bed time for me now but here's a Google search to tide you over. Perhaps tomorrow I can go into more detail. Is it a div or text area? A fiddle would be useful. Here's the google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+scroll+to+bottom+of+element&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS655US656&oq=jquery+scroll+to+bottom&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3.19342j0j4&hl=en-US&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8